# AWS : Python Script to Retrieve list of resources are currently in use

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to retrieve the list of resources are currently in used region wise by using python script and boto3 library.

for example script have to give me the out put as follows

Region : us-west-2

service: EC2

//resource list//instance ids //Name

service: VPC

//resource list//VPC ids//Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to do it, but you can achieve this with a few describe calls.

First enumerate through the regions that you use:

```
for regionname in ["us-east-1", "eu-west-1"]
```

Or if you want to check all:

```
ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
regionresponse = ec2client.describe_regions()
for region in regionresponse["Regions"] 
    regionname = region["RegionName"]
```

Then for each region iteration you need to create a new client for each region's endpoint, and describe_instances:

```
    ec2client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=regionname)
    instanceresponse = ec2client.describe_instances()
    for reservation in instanceresponse["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            print(instance["InstanceId"])
```

Do the same describe call for reach resource type you want.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this ? because if i go with this solution i need to create new client for each aws service and script will become bulky.

Comment: No, that's how the AWS api/sdk works. Each region is a seperate entity, with its own endpoints, so requires a seperate connection. If you break it up into methods it shouldn't become bulky.

Answer (score 2):

The `aws_list_all` program [available on GitHub](https://github.com/JohannesEbke/aws_list_all) is written in python and is able to find all of the resources you have created in your account.

Currently it lists all of the resources into JSON files together with their meta-data.  You can work from the [scripts used for the main function](https://github.com/JohannesEbke/aws_list_all/blob/master/aws_list_all/__main__.py) in `aws_list_all` to build your own output.

There's a prototype [in one issue there](https://github.com/JohannesEbke/aws_list_all/issues/25) which demonstrates how to extract the information that you want.  This prototype runs the following on the JSON files

```
cat *.json | tr '"' '\n' | grep '^arn:aws' | sort |  sed 's/:\*$//'  | uniq
```

when you look at the python code behind `aws_list_all` you will see that it is not an easy problem since you need to dynamically discover all the available AWS endpoints.  Basing your work of that script will make things much easier.

Comment: aws_list_all seems to be promising - but how / where do I set the AWS credentials ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to obtain a list of all resources used. You would need to write it yourself.

Alternatively, there are third-party companies offering services that will do this for you (eg [Hava](https://www.hava.io/).

Comment: Thanks John but I want script because it is small module of big script flow so i can use output of this as an input of other module.